# Mouse click is not working on winform application developed using VB6.0 in win 10

Tags: winforms, vb6, sendmessage

I need some inputs on a issue I am facing currently. Application randomly not responding to mouse click event and continue to behave until restart and mouse clicks works on other applications.

**Brief about the application :**

The application is developed in VB 6.0 some time back (i know VB 6.0 is not supported now), its working fine in Win7. The same application running on Win10 have this strange behaviour randomly.

The application is COM ActiveX Exe which as web browser control embedded on the form which is displaying html pages. the html displayed have button and user click on buttons using mouse and it navigates to other pages.

I am sure it not a driver issue.

**Issue I am facing :**
when a mouse is clicked on the button which is on html it navigates to next page. However, sometime the mouse clicked on the html will not be action i.e. it wont navigate to next point. I don't know what trigger this behaviour. until the application is restarted the behaviour continues.

i used spy++ tool to understand the message send to application and i see the windows messages are different in good case and bad case.

i started to notice a lot of WM_SETCURSOR messages

````
<00114> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00115> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00116> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00117> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00118> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00119> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00120> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00121> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00122> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00123> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00124> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00125> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00126> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00127> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00128> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00129> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00130> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00131> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00132> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00133> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00134> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00135> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00136> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00137> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]
<00138> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
<00139> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0200FFFE]

<00140> 000A0688 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False [lResult:00000000]
**<00141> 000A0688 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000A0688 nHittest:FFFE wMouseMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN [wParam:000A0688 lParam:0201 FFFE]** ```
````

From the above message i see there is `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message.

any pointer/guidance on how we can investigate and understand what is causing the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**-- Updated with logs for good case.**

````
00197> 00030808 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0019BB64 [wParam:00000000 lParam:0019BB64]
<00198> 00030808 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lResult:00000000
<00199> 00030808 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0019F08C [wParam:00000000 lParam:0019F08C]
<00200> 00030808 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lResult:00000000
<00201> 00030808 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0019EDDC [wParam:00000000 lParam:0019EDDC]
<00202> 00030808 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lResult:00000000
<00203> 00030808 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0019EC14 [wParam:00000000 lParam:0019EC14]
<00204> 00030808 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lResult:00000000
<00205> 00030808 S WM_CANCELMODE wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000
<00206> 00030808 R WM_CANCELMODE lResult:00000000
<00207> 00030808 S WM_ENABLE fEnable:False [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00208> 00030808 R WM_ENABLE lResult:00000000
<00209> 00030808 S WM_ENABLE fEnable:True [wParam:00000001 lParam:00000000]
<00210> 00030808 R WM_ENABLE lResult:00000000
<00211> 00030808 S WM_NCACTIVATE fActive:False [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00212> 00030808 R WM_NCACTIVATE fDeactivateOK:True [lResult:00000001]
<00213> 00030808 S WM_ACTIVATE fActive:WA_INACTIVE fMinimized:False hwndPrevious:(null) [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00214> 00030808 R WM_ACTIVATE lResult:00000001
<00215> 00030808 S WM_ACTIVATEAPP fActive:False dwThreadID:000014CC [wParam:00000000 lParam:000014CC]
<00216> 00030808 R WM_ACTIVATEAPP lResult:00000000
<00217> 00030808 S WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos:881 yPos:581 [wParam:00000201 lParam:02450371]
<00218> 00030808 R WM_PARENTNOTIFY lResult:00000000
<00219> 00030808 S ...WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:00030808 nHittest:HTCLIENT uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN [wParam:00030808 lParam:02010001] ```
````

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger what happens on the mouse click event? I could imagine the event fails silently in some case.

Comment: Could there be anything like a mouse utility (X-Mouse) running on this PC and interfering?

Comment: its not clear what the difference between messages is in both cases. If possible, please edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. there is no moutse utility running on the machine. i will add the message for good case.